# How to display Autocad DXF on WPF Canvas?

Tags: wpf, canvas, autocad, autocad-plugin, dxf

I am whole new in Autocad using in .NET application. I am working on WPF application that need to import, export and view 2d DXF or DWG file on canvas. I need some general information about how to achieve my goal if possible step by step instruction.

Comment: Perhaps you can revise this WPF project https://github.com/codingdna2/WpfDxfViewer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the [Autodesk View & Data webservice](http://developer.autodesk.com) to show the model as a WebGL viewer on your application. There are some samples on the [link](http://developer.autodesk.com) and you need internet connection in order to have this viewer working.